# Segmentation fault while loading of the library dependencies

Tags: segmentation-fault, ld, openssh, sshd

I have cross-compiled openssh-8.4p1 for mips64_Cavium platform, while linking with openssl-1.1.1h, and zlib_v1.2.11 dynamically. The issue here is that the binary thus created is getting the following SigSEGV as soon as I am trying to run it:

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x575749a0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault
```

While debugging the loading with LD_DEBUG=files the crash log is as follows:

```
     31232:
     31232:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by /mnt/cf/sshd_dyn [0]
     31232:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
     31232:       dynamic: 0x2b3091b0  base: 0x2b309000   size: 0x00164c00
     31232:         entry: 0x2b31fb58  phdr: 0x2b309034  phnum:         11
     31232:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

... and with LD_DEBUG=symbols the crash log is as follows:

```
     31271:     symbol=islower;  lookup in file=/lib32/octeon2/libpthread.so.0 [0]
     31271:     symbol=islower;  lookup in file=/mnt/cf/libc.so.6 [0]
     31271:     symbol=EVP_aes_256_ctr;  lookup in file=/mnt/cf/sshd_dyn [0]
     31271:     symbol=EVP_aes_256_ctr;  lookup in file=/lib32/octeon2/libresolv.so.2 [0]
     31271:     symbol=EVP_aes_256_ctr;  lookup in file=/mnt/cf/libcrypto.so.1.1 [0]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can not figure out why the crash is happening.

**NOTE**
The compilation of zlib is done with

```
CFLAGS="-mabi=n32 -fPIC"
```

where as openssl is configured with

```
CFLAGS="-mabi=n32" ./Configure no-hw linux-generic64 shared
```

OpenSSH8.4 is configured with

```
CC="mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gcc" --with-cflags="-mabi=n32" --with-ldflags="-mabi=n32 -pthread"
```